# Why is calling .empty() before .html() faster?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm populating a table with an ajax call. I'm able to reload the table contents by making another ajax call. The initial request takes 50ms, but any subsequent requests take 2 seconds to update the table. The only difference is that the table is empty for the initial call.

This is a table with many rows and nested tables. The table container starts off with the css display property set to 'none' and tbody empty.

```
<div class="table-container">
    <table>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The table tbody is empty before the first call. I started with this, but subsequent calls take around 2 seconds to load.

```
function LoadData(dataFromAjax) {
    $('.table-container tbody').html(dataFromAjax);
    $('.table-wrapper').css('display','inline-block');
}
```

Calling .empty() beforehand solves the issue (loads in 50-100ms), but I'm not sure why it's necessary.

```
function LoadData(dataFromAjax) {
    $('.table-container tbody').empty();
    $('.table-container tbody').html(dataFromAjax);
    $('.table-wrapper').css('display','inline-block');
}
```

I thought I ready that jQuery empties the children of the target element first when .html() is used. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `html()` function definition of jQuery. There's an attempt to use `innerHTML` where it iterates on all the existing elements. I guess this is where it spends all this time:

```
// See if we can take a shortcut and just use innerHTML
...
try {
  for ( ; i < l; i++ ) {
    elem = this[ i ] || {};

    // Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks
    if ( elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
      jQuery.cleanData( getAll( elem, false ) );
      elem.innerHTML = value;
    }
  }

  elem = 0;

  // If using innerHTML throws an exception, use the fallback method
  } catch ( e ) {}
}

if ( elem ) { // fallback code
  this.empty().append( value );
}
```

Comment: Just calling .innerHTML on the target element was faster and avoided the need to empty the element beforehand. I suppose i'll have to watch for memory leaks.